# Live USB installer not seeing Mac's SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, live-usb, ssd, mac

I'm attempting to install Ubuntu 19.10 on a Mac laptop with an SSD hard drive (specs below) that's been partitioned with a FAT32 GUID partition. I have a working USB installer, rEFIt is installed and can boot from the USB pen drive without a problem. When I launch the Ubuntu installer to install from the USB live session to Mac's SSD, it does not 'see' any hard drives other than the USB pen drive, jumps the installer step to select where to install and states:

"You need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu.
The computer has only 7.7 GB." - It's an 8 GB USB pen drive, so no doubt this is the pen drive.

SIP is disabled, and I've also disabled all startup disk restrictions. I see comments online about needing to wait for Ubuntu 19.10 because NVMe storage isn't supported until Kernal 5.1.5 ([Ubuntu installer can't see Mac HDD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005504/ubuntu-installer-cant-see-mac-hdd)) - check using that. Also, seeing comments about changing SATA from IDE to ACHI, some say this is unnecessary on a mac, but I tried doing this (based on instructions here: [How to switch from IDE to AHCI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/976071/how-to-switch-from-ide-to-ahci)) and I can't because the pen drive is read-only - `update-initramfs -u` will fail.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Why the installer can't see Mac's SSD?

**UPDATE:** Mmm this seems to be all about the new T2 chip. There is a solution in progress (https://github.com/Dunedan/mbp-2016-linux) but implementing it is a little beyond me at the moment. Has anyone here used this github to fit a Linux install on new Apple hardware and can share how they went about it?

---

Macbook Pro (15 inch, 2019) 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7, OSX 10.14.6 (Mojave)

Comment: Can you see the drive in GParted?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, nothing in Ubuntu seems to work with the new SSD drive macs (keyboard, trackpad etc.) so I've been battling these to get back to installing. No the SSD drives are not visible in GParted, only the USB pen drive is visible as one partition.

Comment: Same problem here... 
As far as I have read, you could *technically* use an ext4 kernel extension and then install linux using macos... 
Otherwise you are just doomed to wait or write a kernel extension for linux yourself...